Issue in UI with @Observable
I migrated from an ObservableObject to the @Observable macro and I am now experiencing an issue with a simple functionality.
I have an enum Reaction:
enum Reaction: CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case like, dislike, love

    var id: Self { self }

    var systemImageName: String {
        switch self {
            case .like: "hand.thumbsup"
            case .dislike: "hand.thumbsdown"
            case .love: "heart"
        }
    }
    var selectedSystemImageName: String {
        systemImageName + ".fill"
    }
}

In the viewModel I handle the choice of the user and set the chosen reaction:
@Observable
class ViewModel {
    var reaction: Reaction?

    func set(_ newReaction: Reaction) async {
        // Here goes a DB update
        reaction = newReaction == reaction ? nil : newReaction
    }
}

And the view is displaying all the cases, you can change the selected reaction or cancel the existing one on tap:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 40) {
            ForEach(Reaction.allCases) { reaction in
                Image(systemName: viewModel.reaction == reaction ? reaction.selectedSystemImageName : reaction.systemImageName)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        Task {
                            await viewModel.set(reaction)
                        }
                    }

            }
        }
    }
}

It was working fine before migrating to @Observable but now the UI does not reflect the reaction value and I can obtain this:

Of course this is not supposed to be possible...
Any idea why ?

Mark the set function with @MainActor, there's a warning about violating actor isolation.

Thank you @vadian, the method indeed publish changes in a background thread but there's no purple warning.
This video describes exactly my issue: https://youtu.be/4dQOnNYjO58

@Observable is for model classes and you wouldn't normally have async funcs inside them, those would be in the database controller struct instead.

I cannot reproduce on iOS 17.4 or macOS 14.1. What did you do to select two reactions at once?

As sweeper said it is not reproducible. The only way it is reproducible was changing condition to viewModel.reaction != reaction

There is nothing more than this code, when you tap the images you will eventually encounter issues.

Could not replicate your issue either, all works well for me in my tests.
On MacOS 14.5, using Xcode 15.4, tested on real ios 17 devices and macCatalyst.
